# making a jquery expandable collapsable box with state indication?

Tags: jquery, state, toggle

I have tried for some time to create a collapsable / expandable div with jquery to build a "basic" and "Advanched" search box to no avail.

- Expand or Collapsa a div
- Change the text on the div depending on what state we ware
- Change "indication arrow" to close or expand depending on what state we are
- Optional: save the state in a cookie so on page refresh it stores

[image]

I cameup with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#container_search').show();

if ($.cookie('status_basic') == 1) {
    //$('#container_search').show();
    //$('#container_search_advanched').hide();
}

if ($.cookie('status_basic') == 0) {
    //$('#container_search_advanched').show();
    //$('#container_search').hide();
    }

});

function advanched() {
    //$('#container_search').show();
    //$('#container_search_advanched').hide();
}

function basic() {
    //$('#container_search').hide();
    //$('#container_search_advanched').show();
}
```

But im tackling it to complicated, is there any plugin that could do this almost by default or has anyone implemented something like this and has some guidelines on how to best tackle this problem in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code.You can use the slideDown and slideUp functions to achieve the desired purpose.

```
// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
}); 

// Collapse Panel
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: This does NOT deliver 2 different div's ( basic  / advanced ) it only slides a single div open/closed